# How To Understand Geological Directions?

Tags: geolocation, township-range-section

I was reading a "Guide to Some Minerals and Rocks in Indiana," which was published in the 1950s, and in it there were these bewildering directions:

"Bluff along Mud Pine Creek 1.5 miles west of Rainsville, SW 1/ 4NE1/ 4sec. 29, T. 23 N., R. 8 W."

It is on p.38 of this pdf: https://scholarworks.iu.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/2022/235/C04.pdf?sequence=1

How may those directions be made understandable?

Comment: If its related to the US Geological Survey this may help: http://store.usgs.gov/b2c_usgs/usgs/maplocator/(ctype=areaDetails&xcm=r3standardpitrex_prd&carea=%24ROOT&layout=6_1_61_48&uiarea=2)/.do

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SW 1/ 4NE1/ 4sec. 29, T. 23 N., R. 8 W is not a direction, it's a location. Specifically, it is the southwest quarter of the NE quarter section of section 29, township 23 North, range 8 West. These terms are with respect to the [public lands survey system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Land_Survey_System) (PLSS). 
Using the  [BLM Interactive map](http://www.geocommunicator.gov/blmMap/MapLSIS.jsp) I navigated to this location and then eyeballed the SW quarter of the NE quarter section and get a lat/lon of 40.412643, -87.347025. This is roughly where Mud Pine Creek meets CR650.

Here's what the map looks like with the cursor pointing to the approximate location.
[image]

Comment: nice answer!!just about i was to post :-)